# Need help with finding the particular solution to the inhomogeneous ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> **Problem:** Find a particular solution of the following inhomogeneous ODE:
> $$u'(x)+u(x)=r(x)$$for $$r(x)=\left\{\begin{aligned}1, \quad 0<x<1 \\ 0, \quad \quad \quad \text{else} \end{aligned} \right.$$**Hint:** You can either evaluate tje convolution integral directly, or you can use  the fact  that $$r(x)=\Theta(x)-\Theta(x-1) $$

The hint is to be using the heaviside unit step function to solve this. Ive been stuck on this problem for the past $3$ hours. Please help!

Comment: Can you use Laplace transform?

Comment: No, the way my professor want the problem solved is by use of convolutions and the heavy side function. So we need to integrate the problem to find the answer.

Comment: Do you know what the convolution integral is?

Comment: A particular solution to this differential equation with initial condition $(x_0,y_0)$ is $$u(x)=e^{-x}\int_{x_0}^xe^{\tau}r({\tau})d\tau+y_0$$